# Salvar arquivos do diretório download com flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou gerando um arquivo em PDF e quero salvar ele nos "downloads" do dispositivo mobile, estou usando o "downloads_path_provider: ^0.1.0" para tal porém quando vou salvar tenho o seguinte erro:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Download'/example.pdf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

o código em si está bem simples pois ainda estou começando:

```
teste() async {
//  Directory documentDirectory  = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

//  String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
 Directory downloadsDirectory;
 final doc = pw.Document();
 try {
   downloadsDirectory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
 } on PlatformException {
   print('Could not get the downloads directory');
 }
 print(downloadsDirectory);
 doc.addPage(
   pw.Page(
     build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Center(
       child: pw.Text('batata'),
     ),
   ),
 );
 File file = File("$downloadsDirectory/example.pdf");

 file.writeAsBytesSync(doc.save());
}
```

Achei que poderia ser pelo fato de usar um emulador mas tive o mesmo problema no dispositivo real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na mensagem de erro podemos ver que:

> path = 'Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Download'/example.pdf'

Ou seja, ele acha que o caminho fornecido por você é

`Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Download'/example.pdf`

Isso não é um caminho válido (tem esse "Directory:" no começo e as aspas).

Isso ocorre porque você está formando sua string de caminho com a classe Directory diretamente. Seu método `toString()` retorna uma descrição da classe em si, e não apenas o caminho.

Experimente usar a propriedade [path](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-io/Directory/path.html) da classe Directory:

Isto é, substitua a seguinte linha:

```
File file = File("$downloadsDirectory/example.pdf");
```

por:

```
File file = File("${downloadsDirectory.path}/example.pdf");
```